# Jenkins version history with java version requirement

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins from Turnkey linux that I setup about 3 years ago.  I went to try and update Jenkins and now the service is failing because I don't have the correct version of Java.  I want to go back to the version of jenkins that I was using, but I foolishly didn't record which version I had.  Which version of jenkins supports the java version below?

```
java version "1.7.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.13) (7u171-2.6.13-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.171-b02, mixed mode)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could have saved yourself a bit of grief and searched the LTS notes:
https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.60.2
- 2.60.1 is the first Jenkins LTS release that requires Java 8 to run.
- Jenkins (master and agents) now requires Java 8 to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found through trial and error.
version 2.46.3